# How to use Phoenix.Channel.reply/2 for async reply to channel push

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm trying to extend the example of **Phoenix.Channel.reply/2** from the Phoenix documentation into a fully working example of asynchronously replying to Phoenix channel/socket push events:

> Taken from https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#reply/2:
>
> ```
> def handle_in("work", payload, socket) do
>   Worker.perform(payload, socket_ref(socket))
>   {:noreply, socket}
> end
>
> def handle_info({:work_complete, result, ref}, socket) do
>   reply ref, {:ok, result}
>   {:noreply, socket}
> end
> ```

I've reworked the example as follows:

## room_channels.ex

```
...
def handle_in("work", job, socket) do
  send worker_pid, {self, job}
  {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_info({:work_complete, result}, socket) do
  broadcast socket, "work_complete", %{result: result}
  {:noreply, socket}
end
...
```

## worker.ex

```
...
receive do
  {pid, job} ->
    result = perform(job) # stub
    send pid, {:work_complete, result}
end
...
```

This solution works, but it doesn't rely on generating and passing a socket_ref with `socket_ref(socket)` and on **Phoenix.Channel.reply/2**. Instead it relies on **Phoenix.Channel.broadcast/3**.

The documentation implies that **reply/2** is specifically used for this scenario of asynchronously replying to socket push events:

> **reply(arg1, arg2)**
>
> Replies asynchronously to a socket push.
>
> Useful when you need to reply to a push that can’t otherwise be
>   handled using the {:reply, {status, payload}, socket} return from your
>   handle_in callbacks. reply/3 will be used in the rare cases you need
>   to perform work in another process and reply when finished by
>   generating a reference to the push with socket_ref/1.

When I generate and pass a socket_ref, and rely on **Phoenix.Channel.reply/2** for asynchronous replies to socket push, I don't get it to work at all:

## room_channels.ex

```
...
def handle_in("work", job, socket) do
  send worker_pid, {self, job, socket_ref(socket)}
  {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_info({:work_complete, result, ref}, socket) do
  reply ref, {:ok, result}
  {:noreply, socket}
end
...
```

## worker.ex

```
...
receive do
  {pid, job, ref} ->
    result = perform(job) # stub
    send pid, {:work_complete, result, ref}
end
...
```

My room_channels.ex `handle_info` function is called but **reply/2** doesn't seem to send a message down the socket. I see no stacktrace on stderr or any output on stdout to indicate an error either. What is more, keeping track of a socket_ref seems to just add overhead to my code.

What is the benefit of using a socket_ref and **reply/2** over my solution with **broadcast/3** and how can I get the solution with **reply/2** to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, the example with **Phoenix.Channel.reply/2** will work:

## room_channels.ex

```
...
def handle_in("work", job, socket) do
  send worker_pid, {self, job, socket_ref(socket)}
  {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_info({:work_complete, result, ref}, socket) do
  reply ref, {:ok, result}
  {:noreply, socket}
end
...
```

## worker.ex

```
...
receive do
  {pid, job, ref} ->
    result = perform(job) # stub
    send pid, {:work_complete, result, ref}
end
...
```

In my implementation I made the mistake of sending a synchronous reply to the event push with the return value of `{:reply, :ok, socket}` instead of `{:noreply, socket}`.

On closer inspection of the websocket frames send from the server to the client, I found that the browser did receive my server replies from `reply ref, {:ok, result}` but that the associated callback was never called.

It seems that Phoenix' Socket.js client library accepts at most a single reply per push events.

Answer (score 0):

hope I'm not too late to this conversation.

I managed to use your code above and got the callback to work in the javascript.

The trick is to listen to the `phx_reply` event. Inside `priv/static/app.js` each `Channel` javascript object has a list of predefined in `CHANNEL_EVENTS` (line  and is set to listen on it at the following code block:

```
this.on(CHANNEL_EVENTS.reply, function (payload, ref) {
  _this2.trigger(_this2.replyEventName(ref), payload);
});
```

What I did was within the channel `on` callback, I listen for the `phx_reply` event:

```
channel.on("phx_reply", (data) => {
  console.log("DATA ", data);
  // Process the data
}
```

This has been tested on Elixir 1.3 and Phoenix 1.2

Hope that helps!